# JNI Okhttp inner class method with NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, okhttp, jnienv

I am trying to access `OkHttpClient.Builder` method using builder object but I am getting `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError exception` in Android.

Here is my code

```
//okHttpClient
    jclass okHttpClassBuilderClass =env->FindClass("okhttp3/OkHttpClient$Builder");
    jmethodID initBuilder =  env->GetMethodID(okHttpClassBuilderClass, "<init>", "()V");
    jobject okHttpClassBuilder = env->NewObject(okHttpClassBuilderClass, initBuilder);

    jclass timeUnitClass = env->FindClass("java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit");
    jfieldID timeUnitClassMethod =  env->GetStaticFieldID(timeUnitClass, "MILLISECONDS", "Ljava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;");
    jobject timeUnitObject = env->GetStaticObjectField(timeUnitClass,timeUnitClassMethod);

    jlong timeout =5000;
    jmethodID setConnTimeoutMethod = env->GetMethodID(okHttpClassBuilderClass, "connectTimeout", "(J;Ljava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;)Lokhttp3/OkHttpClient$Builder;");
    okHttpClassBuilder =env->CallObjectMethod(okHttpClassBuilder,setConnTimeoutMethod,timeout,timeUnitObject);
```

Here is error

> JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI CallObjectMethodV called with pending exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lokhttp3/OkHttpClient$Builder;.connectTimeout(J;Ljava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;)Lokhttp3/OkHttpClient$Builder;"

In error I am getting error like JNI **`CallObjectMethodV`** called but in code I am using **`CallObjectMethod`**

What I am missing here ?

Comment: If you have a lot of config, is it worth defining a builder method of your own, and just calling that from JNI, so you only have one call over the native boundary?

Comment: Yes, I am going to try this. it would be easy to manage and change configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert here, but javap suggests you have an additional ;

```
  public final okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder connectTimeout(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit);
    descriptor: (JLjava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;)Lokhttp3/OkHttpClient$Builder;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @Yuri. I am already using javap for JNI code.

Comment: Yeah I don't think you need `;` after `J`.

Comment: @JesseWilson still getting same error :(

Comment: @JesseWilson and  Yuri,  I found that using JNI we can not access kotlin inner class methods. For JNI support in inner class methods in these methods  should have JvmName annotation. As of now I fall back to okhttp version 3.14.9 and its working as expected.

Comment: This is a static nested class.  It should work, and there seems to be enough evidence out there it can work. https://www.programmersought.net/article/343897566.html. But hey, if it works for you.  3.14.9 is not a maintained version, so you may still want to try calling a java factory method you define.

Comment: Builder class is final class as per javap -s  -> `public final class okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder`. Yes its working for static nested class. As of now I am opting for factory method as per your suggestion.